# Print page created with javascript not styling according to css

Tags: javascript, css, printing, popup, window

I have a `div` with `id` `target_wrapper`.

```
<div id="target_warpper">
      <div id="target">
      ///Some content here
      </div> 
</div>
```

And the corresponding javascript function to print the page is :

```
<div class="print_list">
                        <a href="javascript:PrintContent()">Print</a>
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    function PrintContent() 
                    {


                        var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById('target_warpper');
                        var WindowObject = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes');


                        WindowObject.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE html>');
                        WindowObject.document.writeln('<html><head><title></title>');
                        WindowObject.document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css">');
                        WindowObject.document.writeln('</head><body>')

                        WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);

                        WindowObject.document.writeln('</body></html>');

                        WindowObject.document.close();
                        WindowObject.focus();
                        WindowObject.print();
                        WindowObject.close();
                    }
                    </script>
```

But when I click on the `Print` link, the page that appears does not contain the `css` `css/print/css` I have included.

NB: When I click on the view page source for the print pop up window, it shows blank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example showing this code working in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zmqzb/).  I included jQuery just to make the event bind on the click a little easier.

When you comment out the `print()` & `close()` - its a lot easier to check what happens.  In that example, I appear to get exactly what you want.  New window, correct content, `link` tag with the right `href` attribute.

If you are having trouble with the css file, double check the file path. To be easier, you should probably just specify the full url for the css file: `http://example.com/css/print.css`.